# mongoose count() function with regex case insensitive matching sub string also

Tags: regex, node.js, count, mongoose, case-insensitive

I am trying to find out a simple solution to handle case sensitive email using regex, so far it works good when inserting/querying the document using Mongoose but when I'm validating if the user exists using the Model.count method, its not working as expected.

I have defined this static function in the schema, which takes the username and return the count of occurance in the collection.

```
userSchema.statics.exist = function(username, cb){
  this.count({ "username": new RegExp(username, "i") }, cb);
};
```

and I have a controller function which calls this static like this:

```
userExist: function (req, res) {
  UserModel.exist(req.body.username, function (err, count) {
      res.json({exist: count});
  });
}
```

if I pass ***user@example.com*** in the req.body.username field ( where user@example.com exist in the database), it returns **1**

but its returning **1** even if I enter I enter ***user@examp*** or ***user@exampl*** or  ***user@example.c***

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I thought it may be issue with regex, so I tested this regex for validity:

```
var username = "user@example.com";
var pattern = new RegExp(username, "i");
pattern.match("user@examp");  // this returns false
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by changing the regex a little bit like this:

```
userSchema.statics.exist = function(username, cb){
  this.count({ "username": new RegExp('^'+username+'$', 'i') }, cb);
};
```

Hope this helps someone. Any other suggestions are welcome